# What are these long tubes under the wings?

Tags: wing

I wonder what are the elements below the wings (pointed by the black arrows in the image). I'm not referring to the sticks at the end of them, which I found them to be "static wicks", used for static electricity discharge.

[image]

Comment: @Simon no he's explicitly *not* talking about the static wicks. But instead about the anti-shock bodies.

Comment: @Simon , as I pointed out in the post, I was not referring to static wicks but to the pods. Thank you ratchetfreak for your dup.

Comment: Doh, I'll delete the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are flap track fairings which contain the flap mechanism.

They are called Küchemann carrots (also called anti-shock or Whitcomb body) and are used to reduce wave drag in transonic speeds.