# What are these vertical slats under the wings of the Be-200?

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification, amphibian

This is a photo of the [Be-200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beriev_Be-200), an amphibious aircraft, taking from a [youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Sui26PR-bY)

[image]

I would like to know **what are all those vertical slats** underneath the wings? What is their purpose? To me they seem to add unnecessary drag.

Note, I'm **not** talking about the little pontoons at the ends of the wing. Between the pontoons and the hull are a bunch of vertical protusions that remind me of wing fences.

Comment: Looking at the pictures on Wikipedia, it looks like they are just fairing covers for the flap extension system.

Answer (score 3):

They are flap track fairings, which contain the flap mechanism. They've already been [discussed elsewhere on this site](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18749/what-are-these-long-tubes-under-the-wings/18750#18750). You can also see them in this photo.

[image: Be 200]

Image from [airvectors.net](http://www.airvectors.net/avbe200.html)

They actually *reduce* the drag by enclosing the flap mechanism.

Comment: So they are also anti-shock bodies? They look radically different from the linked question you provided.

Comment: @DrZ214 In this particular case, I don't think they serve that purpose, instead acting only as a cover for the flap mechanism.

Comment: I suppose the question was more about the object on the outer wing, most likely to float on the water and prevent the wing tip from touching the water during landing or takeoff

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the pods on the outer wing, they are "underwing stabiliser floats" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beriev_Be-200#cite_note-EADS-16)).

> The underwing stabiliser floats fitted on wings provide stability in water. ([from naval-technology](http://www.naval-technology.com/projects/berievbe200multipurp/))

I think they also prevent the wing tip to touch the water while landing. Also, it is common in Aircraft design to put weight near the tip of the wing to reduce the root bending moment ([from another forum for example](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwi02Lrg2trSAhVCWxQKHbgkDJwQFghHMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.ubi.com%2Farchive%2Findex.php%2Ft-184344.html&usg=AFQjCNFQtN-B4ANGJtu576z1C14OGZJbCA&bvm=bv.149397726,d.d24))

Comment: The last sentence of the OP's post says that they are specifically **not** talking about the pods on the outer wing.